# how to return values from thread

Tags: java, multithreading, jsp

i have a thread that loop infinetely and reads from a common area (singleton class). Another process (jsp page) produce an input for the common area. The first thread is wake up and elaborate the data into the common area producing some logs. This log is correctly produced into the console and the process works fine. Now i need to pass each row of the log at runtime to the jsp page that prints the log into a textarea.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. My problem is a little difference. I need the log at runtime therefore during the execution of the thread. I don't need the entire log when the thread is finished.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `Callable<T>` and overridde its `public T call() throws Exception` method to get return type of `T`.

Get the official doc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html)

Answer (score 1):

We can use Callable and Future in Java to get results from threads and to allow our threads to throw exceptions. I learnt the concept with the help of following video tutorial: 
https://www.caveofprogramming.com/java-multithreading/java-multithreading-callable-future-video-tutorial-part-13.html